# Adding UIButtonBarItem programmatically to UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

I'am trying to add UIButtonBarItem programmatically to UINavigationBar. I have this class Topbar, that a import on some of my ViewControllers, and then invoke by: `[self.view addSubview:[Topbar insertTopbar]];`

```
#import "Topbar.h"

@implementation Topbar

+(UINavigationBar*)insertTopbar
{
    UINavigationBar *navBar = [ [UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];

    UINavigationItem *navTitle = [UINavigationItem alloc];
    navTitle.title = @"MyApp";

    UINavigationItem *navAdd = [UINavigationItem alloc];
    navAdd.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(addFood)];

    [navBar setItems:@[navAdd, navTitle] animated:false];
    return navBar;
}

@end
```

But when i try to set the items using `navBar setItems:@[navAdd, navTitle]` it ads a "Back"-button
[image]

If i then leave out `navTitle`so it reads `navBar setItems:@[navAdd]`, the "+"-sign suddenly appears. It seems like that the "navTitle" pushes into the first item.
[image]

Comment: Have you tried `self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;`?. That looks like the default back that happens because of the pushing view controllers. probably if you hide it, you'll get your +.

Comment: I tried adding it to the viewcontroller, after appending the NavigationBar(like this http://cl.ly/image/0l3a111q260z ), and nothing happens, still that pesky back-button

Comment: Add `self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;` to your viewController's `-(void) viewWillAppear` method. Back button is not getting displayed from your Navigationbar, it is from NavigationController's navigationBar.

Comment: `[UINavigationItem alloc]` - that's terrible! Should `[[UINavigationItem alloc] init]`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out the following method, did some tweeks and is working fine for me now! :)

[image]

```
-(UINavigationBar*)insertTopbar
{
UINavigationBar *navBar = [ [UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
UINavigationItem *navAdd = [UINavigationItem alloc];
navAdd.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(addFood)];
[navBar pushNavigationItem:navAdd animated:YES];
navBar.topItem.title = @"MyApp";
return navBar;
}
```

Comment: It works perfectly! Thanks! The problem was that is was trying to add multiple `UINavigationItem` instead of multiple buttons!